# Can't access settings of my own GitHub repo?

Tags: github

In my team, someone I work with transferred ownership of their repo to me. But now neither of us can access the Settings for the repo!

This is bizarre to me, and I'd appreciate any help. I saw other SO questions about GitHub permissions, but they had to do with push/pull issues, not with accessing the Settings tab on the GitHub website.

[image: GitHub screenshot]

Comment: Is the repo listed under "Your Repositories?"

Comment: @gmdev Yes it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to go to the URL directly:

```
https://github.com/{username}/{repo-name}/settings
```

That takes me to the Settings page. The tab still does not show up normally. It seems to be a bug on the GitHub website.